# C++ pointer to boolean value

Tags: c++, pointers, boolean

I'm having problems trying to implement a class which contains a pointer to a boolean...

```
class BoolHolder {
    public:
    BoolHolder(bool* _state);

    bool* state;
}

BoolHolder::BoolHolder(bool* _state) {
    state = _state;
}

bool testbool = false;

BoolHolder testbool_holder( &testbool );
```

If I do this, testbool_holder.state always reports that it is true, no matter whether testbool itself is true or false

What am I doing wrong? I just want the class to be able to maintain an up to date value for testbool but I don't know how to effect this. Thanks

Comment: At least use a reference if you really want those semantics.

Comment: `state` will always be a non-null pointer and therefore test as `true`; you need `*state`.

Comment: If you want a more standard way of holding a pointer (of any type) look into [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). To create it do e.g. `std::unique_ptr<bool> testbool_holder{new bool{false}};` and to test it do e.g. `if (*testbool_holder)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg test holder doesn't own the bool though.

Comment: And by the way, why use a pointer instead of a reference?

Comment: @chris: currently the semantics of `BoolHolder` allow it to be reseated (by assigning a different value to `state`). You would need to decide whether this behaviour is intentional before you can decide whether to use a reference in place of the pointer.

Comment: @SteveJessop, True, it just sounded from the OP like it wouldn't change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`testbool_holder.state` returns true if state is not a null pointer

`*(testbool_holder.state)` returns the value of the bool pointed to by state

Try this for a more C++ solution

```
class BoolHolder
{
public:
    BoolHolder(bool* state) : state(state) {}
    bool GetState() const { return *state; } // read only
    bool& GetState() { return *state; } // read/write

private:
    bool* state;
}

bool testbool = false;
BoolHolder testbool_holder(&testbool);
if (testbool_holder.GetState()) { .. }
```

Remove the second getter if you only want to allow read access (and maybe change the pointer to `const bool *`) If you want both, then you need both getters. (This is because read/write can't be used to read on a const object).

Comment: If it was me, I would have used a reference instead of a pointer. Same same but different. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I avoid reference members in classes. What if you want to copy the class or change the state later?

Answer (score 1):

It's right. What you have is not the value of the boolean but a pointer to the boolean. You must dereference the pointer to obtain the value of the bool itself. Since you have a pointer, it will contain an address which is an integer. Since in C and C++ all non zero integers are true, you will get true.