# AVX2 support in GCC 5 and later

Tags: c++, gcc, avx2

I wrote the following class "T" to accelerate manipulations of
"sets of characters" using AVX2. Then I found that it doesn't work in
gcc 5 and later when I use "-O3".
Can anyone help me trace this down to some programming construct that
is known not to work on the latest compilers/systems?

How this code works: The underlying structure ("_bits") is a block of 256 bytes (aligned and allocated for AVX2), which can be accessed either as char[256] or AVX2 elements, depending on whether an element is accessed or the whole thing is used in a vector operation. Seems like it should work perfectly well on the AVX2 platform. No?

This is really hard to debug, because "valgrind" says it's clean,
and I can't use a debugger (due to the problem disappearing when
I remove "-O3"). But I am not happy with just going with the "|="
workaround because if this code is really wrong, then I'm probably
making the same mistake in other places and screwing up everything
I develop!

It is interesting to note that the "|" operator has the problem but the
"|=" does not. Could the problem be related to returning a struct from
a function? But I thought that returning a struct has worked since 1990
or something.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -mavx2 -O3 gcc_fail.cpp

#include "assert.h"
#include "immintrin.h" // AVX

class T {
public:
  __m256i _bits[8];
  inline bool& operator[](unsigned char c)       {return ((bool*)_bits)[c];}
  inline bool  operator[](unsigned char c) const {return ((bool*)_bits)[c];}
  inline          T()                   {}
  inline explicit T(char const*);
  inline T     operator| (T const& b) const;
  inline T &   operator|=(T const& b);
  inline bool  operator! ()           const;
};

T::T(char const* s)
{
  _bits[0] = _bits[1] = _bits[2] = _bits[3] = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
  _bits[4] = _bits[5] = _bits[6] = _bits[7] = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
  char c;
  while ((c = *s++))
    (*this)[c] = true;
}

T T::operator| (T const& b) const
{
  T res;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    res._bits[i] = _mm256_or_si256(_bits[i], b._bits[i]);


  // FIXME why does the above code fail with -O3 in new gcc?
  for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
    assert(res[i] == ((*this)[i] || b[i]));
  // gcc 4.7.0 - PASS
  // gcc 4.7.2 - PASS
  // gcc 4.8.0 - PASS
  // gcc 4.9.2 - PASS
  // gcc 5.2.0 - FAIL
  // gcc 5.3.0 - FAIL
  // gcc 5.3.1 - FAIL
  // gcc 6.1.0 - FAIL


  return res;
}

T & T::operator|=(T const& b)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    _bits[i] = _mm256_or_si256(_bits[i], b._bits[i]);
  return *this;
}

bool T::operator! () const
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (!_mm256_testz_si256(_bits[i], _bits[i]))
      return false;
  return true;
}

int Main()
{
  T sep (" ,\t\n");
  T end ("");
  return !(sep|end);
}

int main()
{
  return Main();
}
```

Comment: Optimization doesn't stop you from adding symbol information.

Comment: Yes, I can get symbols, but all the variables are printed as "optimized out" in gdb.

Comment: I wonder if it's the "bool*"? If I change it to "char*" it works. I hadn't realized they were different. Researching...

Comment: I was just about to say that changing `bool` to  `unsigned char` fixes your problem. Remember that `bool` is only guaranteed to be able to hold `true` or `false` (typically `0` or `1`) and that the compiler is allowed to assume that such a variable won't hold anything else.

Comment: In that case, is there any reliable meaning to "(bool*)_bits"? For that matter, is "(char*)_bits" reliable? And how can these be different given that sizeof(char) = sizeof(bool) = 1

Comment: The funny thing is that (bool*)_bits does exactly what I expect when used in the operator[]. I only have to change it to (char*)_bits in the T::T(char const*) constructor to get the code working. I guess -O3 just gloms everything together and takes advantage of some assumption that's still not quite clear...

Comment: Actually, the `(bool*)_bits` in the `operator[] const` "always" works, but the one in `operator[]` needs to be changed to `(char*)_bits` to make the code work.

Comment: Given that `bool*` is allowed [(example)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559572/c-pointer-to-boolean-value) and that I am not storing values other than 0/1, and the size of `bool` is 1 byte, I really don't understand why it is failing to access the specified memory locations. (I am not trying to store a non-bool value, as you suggest)

Comment: @personal_cloud `unsigned/signed char*` is treated specially by the compiler in a way that `bool*` is not. `char*` type pointers can alias anything; `bool*` pointers do not. So when you cast `_bits` (which decays to a `__m256d*`) to `bool*`, the compiler is entitled to believe that this new pointer doesn't actually point to `_bits`, since the two pointers are not of the same type.

Comment: Also, what I saw in gdb (when I originally traced this down) was that the (bool*) stuff was working just fine, but the AVX2 operations were not. I was ORing together two sets (one of them nonempty) and then the result (which was passed across compilation units, so gdb could see it) was zero. So the whole bool* thing might be a red herring (if I can double-check what I'm saying).

Comment: @personal_cloud I'm writing up my analysis of the machine code.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I will go with your last explanation. Thinking about this more, the noted problem with "bool*" explains all the observations I have seen to date. Given that -O3 was enabled, what happened was that I was observing what I thought were "inputs" and "outputs" of the `operator|` but in fact the output was completely folded to a constant taking advantage of `bool` properties I had not intended. So AVX2 is not at fault. `bool*` is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code's problem is the use of `bool*` when you should have been using `unsigned char*`, which allowed GCC 5 to proceed with a pointer alias optimization.

The two dumps of the machine code for function `Main()`, produced both by GCC 4.8.5 and 5.3.1, are at the end of this answer in appendix for reference.

Looking at the code:

#### Decompilation

After the prologue, `T sep`'s `_bits` are initialized to zero...

```
  _bits[0] = _bits[1] = _bits[2] = _bits[3] = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
  _bits[4] = _bits[5] = _bits[6] = _bits[7] = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);

  40063d:       c5 fd 7f 44 24 60               vmovdqa %ymm0,0x60(%rsp)
  400643:       c5 fd 7f 44 24 40               vmovdqa %ymm0,0x40(%rsp)
  400649:       c5 fd 7f 44 24 20               vmovdqa %ymm0,0x20(%rsp)
  40064f:       c5 fd 7f 04 24                  vmovdqa %ymm0,(%rsp)
  400654:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 e0 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0xe0(%rsp)
  40065d:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 c0 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0xc0(%rsp)
  400666:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 a0 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0xa0(%rsp)
  40066f:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 80 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x80(%rsp)
```

and then written to in a loop based on `char* s`.

```
  char c;
  while ((c = *s++))
    (*this)[c] = true;

  400680:       48 83 c2 01                     add    $0x1,%rdx
  400684:       c6 04 04 01                     movb   $0x1,(%rsp,%rax,1)
  400688:       0f b6 42 ff                     movzbl -0x1(%rdx),%eax
  40068c:       84 c0                           test   %al,%al
  40068e:       75 f0                           jne    400680 <_Z4Mainv+0x60>
```

Both compilers then initialize `T end` to 0s:

```
  400690:       c5 f9 ef c0                     vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
  400694:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  400696:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 60 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x160(%rsp)
  40069f:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 40 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x140(%rsp)
  4006a8:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 20 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x120(%rsp)
  4006b1:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 00 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x100(%rsp)
  4006ba:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 e0 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x1e0(%rsp)
  4006c3:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 c0 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x1c0(%rsp)
  4006cc:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 a0 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x1a0(%rsp)
  4006d5:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 80 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x180(%rsp)
```

Both compilers then optimize out the `_mm256_or_si256()` operations because `T end` is known to be `0`. But then, GCC 4.8.5 **copies from `T sep` to `T res`** (which is computationally what happens when you OR anything into a zero variable), while GCC 5.3.1 **initializes `T res` to `0`**. It's entitled to do that because in your `operator []` method you cast a pointer of type `__m256i*` to `bool*`, and the compiler is permitted to assume the pointers do not alias. Thus in GCC 4.8.5 you see

```
  4006de:       c5 fd 6f 04 24                  vmovdqa (%rsp),%ymm0
  4006e3:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 00 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x200(%rsp)
  4006ec:       c5 fd 6f 44 24 20               vmovdqa 0x20(%rsp),%ymm0
  4006f2:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 20 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x220(%rsp)
  4006fb:       c5 fd 6f 44 24 40               vmovdqa 0x40(%rsp),%ymm0
  400701:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 40 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x240(%rsp)
  40070a:       c5 fd 6f 44 24 60               vmovdqa 0x60(%rsp),%ymm0
  400710:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 60 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x260(%rsp)
  400719:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 80 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0x80(%rsp),%ymm0
  400722:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 80 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x280(%rsp)
  40072b:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 a0 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0xa0(%rsp),%ymm0
  400734:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 a0 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x2a0(%rsp)
  40073d:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 c0 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0xc0(%rsp),%ymm0
  400746:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 c0 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x2c0(%rsp)
  40074f:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 e0 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0xe0(%rsp),%ymm0
  400758:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 e0 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x2e0(%rsp)
```

while in GCC 5.3.1 you see

```
  4006fa:       c5 fd 7f 85 f0 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x110(%rbp)
  400702:       c5 fd 7f 85 10 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0xf0(%rbp)
  40070a:       c5 fd 7f 85 30 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0xd0(%rbp)
  400712:       c5 fd 7f 85 50 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0xb0(%rbp)
  40071a:       c5 fd 7f 85 70 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x90(%rbp)
  400722:       c5 fd 7f 45 90                  vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x70(%rbp)
  400727:       c5 fd 7f 45 b0                  vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x50(%rbp)
  40072c:       c5 fd 7f 45 d0                  vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x30(%rbp)
```

Whereupon the reads for the `assert()` then fail.

#### The Standard's Ruling on Pointer Aliasing:

ISO C++11 refers to aliasing under the following section, which makes clear that variables of type `__m256i*` cannot be accessed using `bool*`, but may be accessed with a `char*/unsigned char*`:

> #### § 3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]
>
> [...]
>
> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined: [52]
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a `char` or `unsigned char` type.
>
> ---
>
> 52) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

## Appendix

#### GCC 4.8.5:

```
0000000000400620 <_Z4Mainv>:
  400620:       55                              push   %rbp
  400621:       c5 f9 ef c0                     vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
  400625:       ba e5 08 40 00                  mov    $0x4008e5,%edx
  40062a:       b8 20 00 00 00                  mov    $0x20,%eax
  40062f:       48 89 e5                        mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400632:       48 83 e4 e0                     and    $0xffffffffffffffe0,%rsp
  400636:       48 81 ec 00 03 00 00            sub    $0x300,%rsp
  40063d:       c5 fd 7f 44 24 60               vmovdqa %ymm0,0x60(%rsp)
  400643:       c5 fd 7f 44 24 40               vmovdqa %ymm0,0x40(%rsp)
  400649:       c5 fd 7f 44 24 20               vmovdqa %ymm0,0x20(%rsp)
  40064f:       c5 fd 7f 04 24                  vmovdqa %ymm0,(%rsp)
  400654:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 e0 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0xe0(%rsp)
  40065d:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 c0 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0xc0(%rsp)
  400666:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 a0 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0xa0(%rsp)
  40066f:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 80 00 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x80(%rsp)
  400678:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400680:       48 83 c2 01                     add    $0x1,%rdx
  400684:       c6 04 04 01                     movb   $0x1,(%rsp,%rax,1)
  400688:       0f b6 42 ff                     movzbl -0x1(%rdx),%eax
  40068c:       84 c0                           test   %al,%al
  40068e:       75 f0                           jne    400680 <_Z4Mainv+0x60>
  400690:       c5 f9 ef c0                     vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
  400694:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  400696:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 60 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x160(%rsp)
  40069f:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 40 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x140(%rsp)
  4006a8:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 20 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x120(%rsp)
  4006b1:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 00 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x100(%rsp)
  4006ba:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 e0 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x1e0(%rsp)
  4006c3:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 c0 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x1c0(%rsp)
  4006cc:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 a0 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x1a0(%rsp)
  4006d5:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 80 01 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x180(%rsp)
  4006de:       c5 fd 6f 04 24                  vmovdqa (%rsp),%ymm0
  4006e3:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 00 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x200(%rsp)
  4006ec:       c5 fd 6f 44 24 20               vmovdqa 0x20(%rsp),%ymm0
  4006f2:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 20 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x220(%rsp)
  4006fb:       c5 fd 6f 44 24 40               vmovdqa 0x40(%rsp),%ymm0
  400701:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 40 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x240(%rsp)
  40070a:       c5 fd 6f 44 24 60               vmovdqa 0x60(%rsp),%ymm0
  400710:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 60 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x260(%rsp)
  400719:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 80 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0x80(%rsp),%ymm0
  400722:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 80 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x280(%rsp)
  40072b:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 a0 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0xa0(%rsp),%ymm0
  400734:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 a0 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x2a0(%rsp)
  40073d:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 c0 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0xc0(%rsp),%ymm0
  400746:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 c0 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x2c0(%rsp)
  40074f:       c5 fd 6f 84 24 e0 00 00 00      vmovdqa 0xe0(%rsp),%ymm0
  400758:       c5 fd 7f 84 24 e0 02 00 00      vmovdqa %ymm0,0x2e0(%rsp)
  400761:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00            nopl   0x0(%rax)
  400768:       80 3c 04 00                     cmpb   $0x0,(%rsp,%rax,1)
  40076c:       0f b6 8c 04 00 02 00 00         movzbl 0x200(%rsp,%rax,1),%ecx
  400774:       ba 01 00 00 00                  mov    $0x1,%edx
  400779:       75 08                           jne    400783 <_Z4Mainv+0x163>
  40077b:       0f b6 94 04 00 01 00 00         movzbl 0x100(%rsp,%rax,1),%edx
  400783:       38 d1                           cmp    %dl,%cl
  400785:       0f 85 b2 00 00 00               jne    40083d <_Z4Mainv+0x21d>
  40078b:       48 83 c0 01                     add    $0x1,%rax
  40078f:       48 3d 00 01 00 00               cmp    $0x100,%rax
  400795:       75 d1                           jne    400768 <_Z4Mainv+0x148>
  400797:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 00 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x200(%rsp),%ymm1
  4007a0:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  4007a2:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  4007a7:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  4007aa:       0f 85 88 00 00 00               jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  4007b0:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 20 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x220(%rsp),%ymm1
  4007b9:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  4007bb:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  4007c0:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  4007c3:       75 73                           jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  4007c5:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 40 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x240(%rsp),%ymm1
  4007ce:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  4007d0:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  4007d5:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  4007d8:       75 5e                           jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  4007da:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 60 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x260(%rsp),%ymm1
  4007e3:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  4007e5:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  4007ea:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  4007ed:       75 49                           jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  4007ef:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 80 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x280(%rsp),%ymm1
  4007f8:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  4007fa:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  4007ff:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  400802:       75 34                           jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  400804:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 a0 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x2a0(%rsp),%ymm1
  40080d:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  40080f:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  400814:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  400817:       75 1f                           jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  400819:       c5 fd 6f 8c 24 c0 02 00 00      vmovdqa 0x2c0(%rsp),%ymm1
  400822:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  400824:       c4 e2 7d 17 c9                  vptest %ymm1,%ymm1
  400829:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  40082c:       75 0a                           jne    400838 <_Z4Mainv+0x218>
  40082e:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  400830:       c4 e2 7d 17 c0                  vptest %ymm0,%ymm0
  400835:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  400838:       c5 f8 77                        vzeroupper 
  40083b:       c9                              leaveq 
  40083c:       c3                              retq   
  40083d:       b9 20 09 40 00                  mov    $0x400920,%ecx
  400842:       ba 26 00 00 00                  mov    $0x26,%edx
  400847:       be e9 08 40 00                  mov    $0x4008e9,%esi
  40084c:       bf f8 08 40 00                  mov    $0x4008f8,%edi
  400851:       c5 f8 77                        vzeroupper 
  400854:       e8 97 fc ff ff                  callq  4004f0 <__assert_fail@plt>
  400859:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00            nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

#### GCC 5:

```
0000000000400630 <_Z4Mainv>:
  400630:       4c 8d 54 24 08                  lea    0x8(%rsp),%r10
  400635:       48 83 e4 e0                     and    $0xffffffffffffffe0,%rsp
  400639:       b8 20 00 00 00                  mov    $0x20,%eax
  40063e:       c5 f9 ef c0                     vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
  400642:       ba 25 08 40 00                  mov    $0x400825,%edx
  400647:       41 ff 72 f8                     pushq  -0x8(%r10)
  40064b:       55                              push   %rbp
  40064c:       48 89 e5                        mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40064f:       41 52                           push   %r10
  400651:       48 81 ec 08 03 00 00            sub    $0x308,%rsp
  400658:       c5 fd 7f 85 50 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x2b0(%rbp)
  400660:       c5 fd 7f 85 30 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x2d0(%rbp)
  400668:       c5 fd 7f 85 10 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x2f0(%rbp)
  400670:       c5 fd 7f 85 f0 fc ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x310(%rbp)
  400678:       c5 fd 7f 85 d0 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x230(%rbp)
  400680:       c5 fd 7f 85 b0 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x250(%rbp)
  400688:       c5 fd 7f 85 90 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x270(%rbp)
  400690:       c5 fd 7f 85 70 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x290(%rbp)
  400698:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00         nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4006a0:       48 83 c2 01                     add    $0x1,%rdx
  4006a4:       c6 84 05 f0 fc ff ff 01         movb   $0x1,-0x310(%rbp,%rax,1)
  4006ac:       0f b6 42 ff                     movzbl -0x1(%rdx),%eax
  4006b0:       84 c0                           test   %al,%al
  4006b2:       75 ec                           jne    4006a0 <_Z4Mainv+0x70>
  4006b4:       c5 f9 ef c0                     vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
  4006b8:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  4006ba:       c5 fd 7f 85 50 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x1b0(%rbp)
  4006c2:       c5 fd 7f 85 30 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x1d0(%rbp)
  4006ca:       c5 fd 7f 85 10 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x1f0(%rbp)
  4006d2:       c5 fd 7f 85 f0 fd ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x210(%rbp)
  4006da:       c5 fd 7f 85 d0 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x130(%rbp)
  4006e2:       c5 fd 7f 85 b0 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x150(%rbp)
  4006ea:       c5 fd 7f 85 90 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x170(%rbp)
  4006f2:       c5 fd 7f 85 70 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x190(%rbp)
  4006fa:       c5 fd 7f 85 f0 fe ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x110(%rbp)
  400702:       c5 fd 7f 85 10 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0xf0(%rbp)
  40070a:       c5 fd 7f 85 30 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0xd0(%rbp)
  400712:       c5 fd 7f 85 50 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0xb0(%rbp)
  40071a:       c5 fd 7f 85 70 ff ff ff         vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x90(%rbp)
  400722:       c5 fd 7f 45 90                  vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x70(%rbp)
  400727:       c5 fd 7f 45 b0                  vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x50(%rbp)
  40072c:       c5 fd 7f 45 d0                  vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x30(%rbp)
  400731:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00            nopl   0x0(%rax)
  400738:       0f b6 94 05 f0 fc ff ff         movzbl -0x310(%rbp,%rax,1),%edx
  400740:       0f b6 8c 05 f0 fe ff ff         movzbl -0x110(%rbp,%rax,1),%ecx
  400748:       84 d2                           test   %dl,%dl
  40074a:       75 08                           jne    400754 <_Z4Mainv+0x124>
  40074c:       0f b6 94 05 f0 fd ff ff         movzbl -0x210(%rbp,%rax,1),%edx
  400754:       38 d1                           cmp    %dl,%cl
  400756:       75 2c                           jne    400784 <_Z4Mainv+0x154>
  400758:       48 83 c0 01                     add    $0x1,%rax
  40075c:       48 3d 00 01 00 00               cmp    $0x100,%rax
  400762:       75 d4                           jne    400738 <_Z4Mainv+0x108>
  400764:       c5 f9 ef c0                     vpxor  %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
  400768:       31 c0                           xor    %eax,%eax
  40076a:       c4 e2 7d 17 c0                  vptest %ymm0,%ymm0
  40076f:       0f 94 c0                        sete   %al
  400772:       c5 f8 77                        vzeroupper 
  400775:       48 81 c4 08 03 00 00            add    $0x308,%rsp
  40077c:       41 5a                           pop    %r10
  40077e:       5d                              pop    %rbp
  40077f:       49 8d 62 f8                     lea    -0x8(%r10),%rsp
  400783:       c3                              retq   
  400784:       b9 60 08 40 00                  mov    $0x400860,%ecx
  400789:       ba 26 00 00 00                  mov    $0x26,%edx
  40078e:       be 29 08 40 00                  mov    $0x400829,%esi
  400793:       bf 38 08 40 00                  mov    $0x400838,%edi
  400798:       c5 f8 77                        vzeroupper 
  40079b:       e8 50 fd ff ff                  callq  4004f0 <__assert_fail@plt>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can any pointer alias to `bool*`? I tried casting with `(bool*)(char*)_bits` but that didn't work.

Comment: @personal_cloud `void*` and `char*` are allowed to alias anything else, and nothing except those two and `bool*` is allowed to alias `bool*`. Even if you cast `bool*` to `char*` on the way, it doesn't change things; The alias rules hold in terms of the pointer type you use to make the access.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it's missing some explanation of the aliasing rules that the compiler is taking advantage of to optimize `unsigned char`. You state pretty clearly what it *is* doing, but the answer could be improved by adding a few sentences as to *why* (somewhat like your previous comment).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist `void *` is moot because the aliasing rule is defined in terms of the dereferenced expression doing the access, and you can't dereference `void *`.  Also any character type can be used , e.g. `unsigned char`, and const varieties of that etc.

Comment: I tried aliasing `char*` to a pointer to a `struct {bool b;}`, but that seemed to have the same problem: direct assignments to `b` were not visible as `char`s. Maybe the compiler again just sees such code as just another `bool*` to `char*` cast... fascinating.

Comment: @M.M Yes of course you are right; but I alluded to that in my comment above that said _The alias rules hold in terms of the pointer type you use to make the access_ and in a comment under the question that said that this goes for all varieties of `char*`, "neural", `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist each language has its own version of the strict aliasing rule. See section [basic.lval] of C++ standard

Comment: could you people take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964781/why-gcc-autovectorization-does-not-work-on-convolution-matrix-biger-than-3x3)